# What's the correct way to create a Room Entity with two possible Parents?

Tags: android, android-room

I am using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) in Android for the first time. I have one Entity `Comment` which is part of a tree structure. Some comments will be the child of a `Post` while others will be the children of another `Comment`.

The following is my entity declaration

```
@Entity(tableName = "comments,
    foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Post.class, parentColumns = "uid",
                childColumns = "post_uid", onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Comment.class, parentColumns = "uid",
                childColumns = "comment_uid", onDelete = CASCADE)
    }
)
public class Comment {
   ...
}
```

I cant see an option like nullable or required for the [Foreign Key](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html), so what is the correct way to declare that the keys can be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the underlying column allows `NULL`, you should be fine. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.2/General/RoomTree) demonstrates a tree structure, albeit one with only one possible parent. Still, the root of the tree has a `null` parent ID, and if that works, so should `null` for other foreign keys.

Comment: This works with one note: ensure you use boxed objects set to null. A primitive (-1) is not automatically nulled, instead it will throw non-unique exceptions

Comment: @NickCardoso: Correct. Use `Integer` instead of `int`, for example, in foreign keys where `NULL` should be a possible value for the column.

Comment: Wow, Is that Category @Relation all that was necessary to create an adjacency list, did I follow that correctly?  Are full ancestor/descendant queries still complicated or is there a trick for that as well?

Comment: @Anthony: "Is that Category @Relation all that was necessary to create an adjacency list" -- I'm not enough into graph theory to know how an adjacency list applies here. The `@Relation` is not necessary to create a tree structure; the `CategoryShadow` sample class is merely a demonstration of one way to get a node and its children in a single request. "Are full ancestor/descendant queries still complicated or is there a trick for that as well?" -- I do not know how you are defining "full ancestor/descendant queries", sorry.

Comment: I started a new question as this is really outside the scope of the comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757054/how-to-do-full-branch-ancestry-queries-with-room