# How to do full branch ancestry queries with Room?

Tags: tree, android-room

I tried to shoehorn path enumeration into Room.  There are two main filtering use cases:

- Hiding folder A hides descendants AA, AB, etc.
- Alternatively selecting a nested keyword "Bavaria" selects all ancestors "Europe" > "Germany" > "Bavaria".

These tables don't get large so efficiency is less of a concern, so I've begun to implement simple path materialization queries:

```
1 | Europe  | /1
---------------------
2 | Germany | /1/2
---------------------
3 | Bavaria | /1/2/3
---------------------
4 | Asia    | /4
```

Descendants:

```
WHERE :path LIKE column || '%'
```

Ancestors:

```
WHERE column LIKE :path || '%'
```

This requires mapping the path in every insert.  Not a big deal, but not a simple insert.

Can these full branch queries be done easier with Room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution with the new `@RawQuery` in 1.1.0:

https://gist.github.com/rcketscientist/4ded9ae64a770ff6929f27b5dbdbe13a